# Titanium - Android : Scrollview scroll position issue

Tags: javascript, android, titanium, scrollview

I have a scrollable view containing multiple views. I use this scrollable view as a stack.

The issue I have been facing is only occurring on Android, it works fine on iOS.

I have a view containing a scrollview which is in the stack. When I click on some item in this scrollview, it opens a new view which is added to the stack.

Using the back button, you can dismiss this view and come back to the scrollview (the view is popped out of the stack).

The issue is that the scroll position is not kept, so when the user comes back to the scrollview, the scrollbar is at the top.

I'm using Titanium SDK 5.1.1 and android sdk min version is 14 with 23 as target sdk version. I've tested this in android 4.0.4, 4.1.2 and 5.1.1.

Is somebody having the same problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should try to remember the scroll offset, and then restore it. From my own practice after 1.5 years of Titanium development, I can recommend you to stop coding in it and switch to native. I had too many problems when coding in Titanium :).

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you to store your scroll position and after to use `scrollTo(x,y)`

Take a look to the documentation
http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.ScrollView